# Devexpress Create Interactve Form from existing Pdf

Tags: pdf, devexpress

I'm looking for functionality in Devexpress PdfDocumentProcessor that is similar to the Prepare Form in Adobe Acrobat Pro.  I have a PDF form that is just a PDF. It doesn't show any interactive form fields. When you click on Prepare Form it updates the form so you can see the interactive fields.  I need to be able to do this in code so I can access those fields and stamp a signature on it.  I haven't come across anything in the documentation that states it does this.  Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The "Prepare form" feature in Acrobat does not unlock some pre-existing form information in the PDF file. It analyzes the PDF file and generates form fields in the places where it thinks there should be form fields. This is a hit or miss functionality.

You have to implement the same functionality (analysis of the PDF page, generation of the form fields), it is not available by default.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure that there is a way to automatically create form fields in a PDF file, the PdfDocumentProcessor offers a comprehensive API to create/edit/remove them. Perhaps, you will find the following help topic helpful: [Interactive Forms in PDF Documents](https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/118284/pdf-document-api/interactive-forms).